# How to make old landline phone ringer into doorbell

Tags: doorbell, phone-wiring

Ok sorry for the title but I can't think of better wording.

Now I have an old secondary phone ringer that was in my Dad's garage that I took out of there when my mom moved after he passed. You could hear when the phone rang over everything going on in the garage

The house I just bought has a very weak sounding doorbell and it sounds very much like my grandfather clock which happens to sit nearby to the doorbell.

I know doorbells run at 24VAC and phones ring at 90VDC but also operate at 48VDC which is a bit confusing. If I got a converter to make the proper voltage would it be possible to make the ringer work for my doorbell?

It seems like new doorbells are all pretty quiet and even shopping around anything that is reasonably audible is insanely expensive which led me to remember I have that ringer lying around.

If it is possible what would I need to make it work. I have a wired doorbell now and it's a standard 24VDC one. I feel like if I just hit the right wire with the right voltage this thing will ring but I don't know enough about how phones work yet to know what voltage would actually work.

[image: secondary ringer]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run this on a doorbell circuit, the way to do it is by replacing the doorbell transformer with a 'telephone ring generator'. This is a power supply which will put out 60-90V at 20Hz AC. You will also need to remove the light bulb from the lighted doorbell button, if it has one. Other doorbells will not work well on the same circuit. Since this isn't a shopping SE, I can't point you at specific devices to generate the ring, but know that there's a range of new and used options out there from $40+.

Comment: Damn your Google fu is better than mine with that price. Also there is just the 1 doorbell in the house and I can easily remove the light from it and not worry

Comment: Would be safer to have the doorbell circuit close a relay powering the RG. Doorbell wiring is not suitable for the RG voltage.

Comment: Technically a lot of bell wire is only rated for 50V, but I wouldn't worry about typical bell voltage on it as there is no current unless the circuit is closed. After all, ring voltage has been sent for over a hundred years through utterly random house telephone wiring with very little issue. The amounts of total power at play here are fairly small. @rasmukri you might look on eBay, the 'black magic' ones require a power supply as well but are only four wires to connect.